# shared_preferences in Flutter. 10 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints

Tags: flutter, package, sharedpreferences, pubspec

[image]When installing shared_preferences I get an error in the terminal that says 10 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints. Now I can't save data. How do I fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands from your project root directory:

1. `flutter pub outdated`
2. `flutter pub upgrade` or `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

This should solve the problem.

Comment: That only updated two packages. There are still eight packages to go.

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of your pubspec.yaml, flutter version, and, the output when you run the app? @JohnBrown

Comment: I can't seem to fix out how to upload pictures onto the comment section

Comment: Edit your question and put the screenshots in your questions. You got the downvote in your question as there is no clear information in your question.

Comment: Okay I added a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
```

and

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

[for reference go through this](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/288/packages-have-newer-versions-incompatible-error/)